# How to assign a timestamp format value in a parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

```
[Timestamp]
public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
```

How to assign a dummy value to Timestamp ?

Comment: Set the value in the contructor of the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to avoid a null value:

```
Timestamp = new byte[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

## Try this out:-

```
public class Time
{
    [Timestamp]
    private Lazy<byte[]> _timestamp=new Lazy<byte[]>();

    [Timestamp]
    public Lazy<byte[]> Timestamp
    {
        get
        {
            return _timestamp;
        }

        set { _timestamp = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: The pattern can be reduced by using the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx): `return _timestamp = _timestamp ?? new byte[0];`. And the 4.0 framework introduced support for [lazy initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx) which can be used to replace the above pattern.